# Variational Calculus with Discrete Objective

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

I'm trying to infer a *smooth*, non-negative function from some *given data* ($\vec{m},\vec{\alpha},\vec{\beta}$). That is, I want to solve (I think)
$$ \mathop{\arg\!\min}_{g \in C^1((-1,1)\to(0,\infty))} J[g] := \sum_k \left(\Gamma_k[g] - m_k\log\Gamma_k[g]\right) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\int_{-1}^1 g'(x)^2\,dx, $$
where $\Gamma_k[g] = \sum_{i=1}^5 \alpha_{i,k} g(\beta_{i,k})$. The problem is the summation terms are not under an integral operator -- instead, the unknown function $g$ is being evaluated at a set of discrete points, rather than over an interval. (Hence the choice of the Tikhonov penalty, to promote smooth solutions.)

The only way I can think of to proceed is to first map $g(x) \to h(x)=\log{g(x)}$ so that $h:(-\infty,\infty)$, then write $h(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i p_i(x)$ for some choice of orthogonal polynomials, and then simply minimize the objective over $\mathbb{R}^N$. In preliminary investigations, my solutions tended to be very sensitive to $N$, but maybe I simply wasn't choosing $N$ and $\lambda$ large enough.

Is this generally the right way to proceed? I would alternatively love an analytic approach, but I'm not sure how to introduce an integral over the sum.

Comment: To clarify, what are the dimensions of your data?  It looks like $\vec{m}$ is a finite dimensional vector and $\alpha,\beta$ are finite dimensional matrices?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The idea is I have some finite number of samples (indexed by $k$), and each sample comes with 5 values of $\alpha$, 5 values of $\beta$, and 1 value of $m$. Supposing that I have $d$ samples total, then $\vec{m} \in \mathbb{N}^d$, $\vec{\alpha} \in \mathbb{N}^{5 \times d}$, and $\vec{\beta} \in [-1,1]^{5 \times d}$.